# Azure key vault - WebApp is not visible in select principal

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-keyvault

We have 2 subscriptions

- Development
- UAT

We are able to assign webapp to allow access to key vault to get credentials and its working fine thru Key Vault -> Access Policies -> Add New -> Select Principal

With UAT subscription, WebApp is not listed when we want to select it to allow access to read credentials.
I can see APIM is listed but not the webapp.

I checked with app service plan, other default configuration, all looks same.

Are there any more rule applied to the list?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Identity status in Azure portal was in "Off" mode
Webapp -> Settings -> Identity

I changed it to "On" and saved it.

Now i can see webapp inside select principal option.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem from my end.

Answer (score 1):

Web app and Key vault should be in the same tenant when you enable the access policy of key vault for your web app. Taken from [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/key-vault/key-vault-subscription-move-fix#q-my-subscription-was-moved-from-tenant-a-to-tenant-b-how-do-i-change-the-tenant-id-for-my-existing-key-vault-and-set-correct-acls-for-principals-in-tenant-b).

> When you create a new key vault in a subscription, it is automatically
>   tied to the default Azure Active Directory tenant ID for that
>   subscription. All access policy entries are also tied to this tenant
>   ID. **When you move your Azure subscription from tenant A to tenant B,
>   your existing key vaults are inaccessible by the principals (users and
>   applications) in tenant B**. To fix this issue, you need to:
>
> - Change the tenant ID associated with all existing key vaults in this subscription to tenant B.
> - Remove all existing access policy entries.
> - Add new access policy entries that are associated with tenant B.

For example, if you have key vault 'myvault' in a subscription that has been moved from tenant A to tenant B, here's how to change the tenant ID for this key vault and remove old access policies.

```
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId YourSubscriptionID
$vaultResourceId = (Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName myvault).ResourceId
$vault = Get-AzResource –ResourceId $vaultResourceId -ExpandProperties
$vault.Properties.TenantId = (Get-AzContext).Tenant.TenantId
$vault.Properties.AccessPolicies = @()
Set-AzResource -ResourceId $vaultResourceId -Properties $vault.Properties
```

If you want to know moving resources to a new resource group or subscription, read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources).

Comment: Thanks Nancy for your reply. We have only 1 tenant ID for all subscriptions within Azure. Your reply help to me understand more from Azure perspective, Thanks.

Comment: In fact, the issue is that you have not created a service principal for your web app whatever you are in the existing tenant or another tenant according to your reply below. When you enable the MSI, It automatically creates a service principal which you can authenticate with your Azure AD.