# Cannot selects principals on vault acces policy - list is empty. What rights are missing?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to grant my app access to my vault on azure but I have no items on the list. If I search I can't see even my own user, nor anything else.

[image]

I've read the entries on [Azure key vault - WebApp is not visible in select principal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56953538/azure-key-vault-webapp-is-not-visible-in-select-principal) but on my case the id is on and I've the guid.
The thing is, I can't list any Ids at all, and also not search for them.

Which Premission do I need to ask my Admin to grant me?
I thought "Directory Readers" but it seems not to work.

I've currently the following Azure roles:
Azure:Contributor and Key Vault Admin
AD: App Registration

We've temprary added the AD Role: Global Secure Access Administrator and Global Reader and I was able to list the principals including my app.

Cheers,
Marco

Comment: Do you have Key Vault Contributor role and reader role to the user account?

Comment: Which user? I've created both resources myself. The App and the Vault.

Comment: I mean your user account have roles that you have logged in to Azure Portal?

Comment: Yes, my user can log in to the Azure portal. Can create Vaults, but cannot list or search principals.

Comment: Does the user have reader/global reader role?

Comment: nope. It does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: To access Service Principals and users, the user account must be granted with **Global Reader role and Key Vault contributor role** to your user account.

I assigned the role like below:

[image]

After assigning the roles, I am able to see the Service Principals while creating access policy like below:

[image]

**Otherwise**, try assigning Reader role to the user account:

*Go to Subscriptions -> Access control (IAM) -> Add -> Add role assignment*

[image]

Search the application with the **ObjectID** of the Enterprise application:

[image]

Refresh the Key vault page and check if you can find the application.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid this is the answer. I hoped there is a less "global" permssion.